# Integration SwiftPhotoGallery with SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `SDWebImage` in my project `to load and cache images from web`. I want to use [SwiftPhotoGallery](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftPhotoGallery) as a gallery library. In the documentation, it states that "`SwiftPhotoGallery` integrates seamlessly with [SDWebImage](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SDWebImage)".

However I didn't find a way how to integrate. Because SwiftPhotoGallery is working with `UIImages` `(SwiftPhotoGalleryDataSource method required UIImage as a result)` and `SDWebImage` is working with `UIImageViews` (it sets image automatically, when download is finished).

Comment: I think there's one method in SDWebImage which allow you to make operation on image download completion, with completion handler. Please check that out.

Comment: @DipakKacha yes there is, but I think I can't use completion block in that delegate method, which requires UIImage as a result.